# Google+ Background Data Usage

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, data-connection, google-plus

My 1GB data pack (3G) was running out a bit faster than normal, so I started investigating using the Data Usage tool (Android 4.1.2 Nexus S).
That's when I found out the Google+ app had used 300 MB in 3 days, and all of it was background data.
Here's the graph:

[image: graph]
<sup>Graph (click to enlarge)</sup>

I don't remember using the app much at all, yet it almost burned through my data pack. I've set the Instant Upload settings to only upload when connected to Wi-fi, and roaming uploads are disabled too. I disabled background as soon as I figured it out, but I still don't know how and why it used up so much data. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have instant uploads on? Also, most data looks to be used in a short period. After that the graph is almost flat. Just see what did you do with G+ in that period. I personally have never had any issue like this.

Comment: Instant Upload was set to upload only when connected to Wi-fi, so that's not the problem.
I can't remember doing anything with the app in that time, it's background data so it's not that I was interacting with it directly.
And the graph is flat after that because I turned off background data when I figured this out.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are not alone. Please, read: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-plus-discuss/A8jv6QU2q1s/maC6U02QJs4J

Answer (score 0):

Google Photos auto-backup may sync automatically the local photos to account.turn of this feature if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Just check "limit background data" and the app will not use your data volume if it is in the background.

Comment: The questioner already disabled background data. The question is what functionality of the app is making it use so much data to start with.